# Difference between onEndEditing and onBlur?

Tags: react-native

React Native has a TextInput component to accept user inputs and I'm interested in the difference between

**onEndEditing**

> Callback that is called when text input ends.

**onBlur**

> Callback that is called when the text input is blurred.

Is there a scenario where it can't be solved just with `onBlur`, when is `onEndEditing` useful?

Comment: There is a difference between onSubmitEditing. The onSubmitEditing does not get called if multiline=true.

Answer (score 56):

First let me say I was struggling finding the answer to this question!

I believe this is rooted in history since it originates from iOS which has the native event `UIControlEventEditingDidEnd`.  That's probably the naming before `blur` was introduced as an abstraction.

**TL:DR;**

`onEndEditing` should really be deprecated in my opinion, but as of right now you should use it because it is the most platform agnostic version of blur. See below.

Both `onBlur` and `onEndEditing` get an event.  On iOS both of these seem to do the exact same thing, and the event has the native text.  In Android, it is two different events, and only one of them has access to the text.  To me this seems like a bug.

Notice the differences between [Android onEndEditing](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/9ee815f6b52e0c2417c04e5a05e1e31df26daed2/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textinput/ReactTextInputEndEditingEvent.java#L52) and [Android onBlur](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/9ee815f6b52e0c2417c04e5a05e1e31df26daed2/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textinput/ReactTextInputBlurEvent.java#L43).

```
// this is undefined on Android
onBlur={(e) => alert(e.nativeEvent.text)}
```

So if reading the text during a blur, you get cross-platform usability with `onEndEditing` for now.

See [this rnplay](https://rnplay.org/apps/rdiixg) to see the differences in OS

Comment: "I believe this is rooted in history since it originates from iOS":

React Native was iOS-only in the very beginning so this would make sense.

Comment: Looks like these events are not always raised at the same time, at least on Android:
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1b870d201976455303ee176c03a4824eac07e11b/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textinput/ReactTextInputManager.java#L652;L701

Comment: Is using `onEndEditing` instead of  `onBlur` still the best option in 2021?

Answer (score 12):

Looking at the iOS and Android examples, seems like `onEndEditing` is meant to pass the contents of the `TextInput`, while `onBlur` is not meant to pass any data:

- [iOS example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/40e8d8904b006dadab639d4a9fddb926961e658a/Examples/UIExplorer/js/TextInputExample.ios.js#L74;L80)
- [Android example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/e8198aed8d094087d5da898a325916dd44b86d5a/Examples/UIExplorer/js/TextInputExample.android.js#L59;L65)

There is actually a difference between when these events are raised. [Here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1b870d201976455303ee176c03a4824eac07e11b/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/views/textinput/ReactTextInputManager.java#L652;L701) we can see that `onEndEditing` is raised for native Android `onEditorAction`, while `onBlur` is not. The action can be either ["Search"](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/EditorInfo.html) (this corresponds to the special "Search" icon on Android keyboards), although I don't know what React Native API lets you display these action icons as part of the keyboard.

In general, looking at [examples](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/40e8d8904b006dadab639d4a9fddb926961e658a/Examples/UIExplorer/js) / implementation is a good way to understand something that's not documented well enough.

If this is unclear in the JS docs, please submit a pull request to clarify it. If the implementation does something that doesn't make sense or is inconsistent between platforms, please submit a pull request to fix the implementation. This should help others.